# EnqueueNDRange Kernel Sequence

Tags: opencl

If I call EnqueueNDRange with maximum local group size and some large global group size, can I be sure that the local group kernels will be executed inorder?

i.e:

```
 Global 0 : Local 0 1 2 3 4
 Global 5 : Local 0 1 2 3 4
 Global 10 : Local 0 1 2 3 4
 etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the arguments global_work_size parameter specifies number of work items in each dimension of the NDRange and local_work_size specifies number of work items in each dimension of the workgroup.

All the workitems and workgroups are supposed to run in parallel, while work items within workgroup goes in lockstep manner, different workgroups will execute different SIMD engine but they are supposed to run in parallel, unless there is hardware limitation on GPU in terms of number of SIMD engines available, wave/warp scheduler limitation etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that work items within the same group will run in order. This is why you need to used a barrier to sync the group at important points in the kernel. Differences in gpu hardware between cards makes it fairly obvious why items may not execute in order. Even the way you access memory can mean the work items are rarely synchronized -- even for a specific gpu you are optimizing for.